# Getting the most recent filename where the extension name is case *in*sensitive

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command-line-interface, ksh

I am trying to get the most recent .CSV or .csv file name among other comma separated value files where the extension name is case insensitive.

I am achieving this with the following command, provided by someone else without any explanation:

```
ls -t ~(i:*.CSV) | head -1
```

or

```
ls -t -- ~(i:*.CSV) | head -1
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the use of `~` and `--` in this case? Does -- helps here?
2. How can I get a blank response when there is no .csv or .CSV file in
   the folder? At the moment I get:
   `/bin/ls: cannot access ~(i:*.CSV): No such file or directory`

I know I can test the exit code of the last command, but I was wondering maybe there is a `--silent` option or something.

Many thanks for your time.

PS: I made my research online quite thorough and I was unable to find an answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's **Korn Shell** I'm using on RHEL7.
Thanks all for the swift answers!

Answer (score 1):

`~(i:*.CSV)` is to tell to shell (this is only supported apparently in ksh93) the enclosed text after `:` must be treated as insensitive, so in this example that could all these possibilites.

- `*.csv` or
- `*.Csv` or
- `*.cSv` or
- `*.csV` or
- `*.CSv` or
- `*.CSV`

Note this could have been written `ls -t *.[CcSsVv]` in bash.

To silent errors I suggest you to look for in this site for "standard error /dev/null" that will help.

Comment: Which version of `bash` supports that?

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought that I had tried `ksh`, but I didn't realize that `~` was part of the syntax, and not a literal character.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` is just a literal character; the intent would appear to be to match filenames starting with `~` and ending with `.csv`, with `i:` being a flag to make the match case-insensitive. However, I don't know of *any* shell that supports that particular syntax. The closest thing I am aware of would be `zsh`'s globbing flags:

```
setopt extended_glob  # Allow globbing flags
ls ~(#i)*.csv
```

Here, `(#i)` indicates that anything *after* it should be matched without regard to case.

Update: as @baptistemm points out, `~(i:...)` is syntax defined by `ksh`.

The `--` is a conventional argument, supported by many commands, to mean that any arguments that follow are not options, but should be treated literally. For example, `ls -l` would mean `ls` should use the `-l` option to modify its output, while `ls -- -l` means `ls` should try to list a file named `-l`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running commands like what you have in both `bash` and `zsh` and neither worked, so I can't help you out with that, but if you want to discard the error, you can add `2>/dev/null` to the end of the `ls` command, so your command would look like the following:

```
ls -t ~(i:*.CSV) 2>/dev/null | head -1
```

This will redirect anything written to `STDERR` to /dev/null (i.e. throw it out), which, in your case, would be `/bin/ls: cannot access ~(i:*.CSV): No such file or directory`.